# Qt QMap and QList speed

Tags: performance, qt

What is faster:
`QMap`, access elements via `[]` operator

```
QMap<int, QString> qmap;
//add some elements
QString value = qmap[key];
```

or `QList`, key as a class member:

```
QList<MyClass*> qlist;
//add some elements
for (int i = 0; i < qlist.length(); ++i)
{
    if (qlist[i].key == KEY)
    {
        MyClass *value = qlist[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not benchmark it?

Comment: I guess as the collection size increases the map will be faster than the list. I mean for random lookups. A hash or a set will be even faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should benchmark the performance with your data (most important is the size of the container) for sufficiently large container i expect the QMap to be faster than a sequential search into a vector.

But a very important note: use [find](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmap.html#find) to get an element from a QMap (or a std::map) associated with key, because [operator[]](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d) inserts an element if the key is not found in the container.

Also for a big data you can take a look at (and benchmark) [QHash](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qhash.html#details) too.

LE: [this](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/containers.html) documentation page provides some comparison for the "QContainers"

Comment: "...QMap to be faster than a sequential search into a vector" - is `QList` even sequential? It is faster at arbitrary inserts and prepending, so I guess not..

Comment: @ddriver i didn't read it's source but as far as i know is implemented as an array, but it has the internal buffer allocated before the beginning (external [0]) and after the end (external [size-1]) so it can insert elements at the beginning without having to move all the data so it has amortized constant complexity for inserting at both beginning and end, for anywhere else insert is O(n).